# Get project cost from ActiveCollab API

Tags: api, activecollab

I would like to know how can i export by the API the Cost of a project
The cost element is present on this page: https://activecollab.com/help/books/budgeting/profitability

I try with GET /projects/1/budget but i don't have this value

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can GET `/api/v1/projects/:project-id/financial-stats` and you'll receive project profitability data. Note that only owners, project leader and people with permission to manage financials can access this project API.